# How can I get the predicted YValidation data using LSTM model in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, validation, lstm

I did a LSTM model, in the [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/trainnetwork.html). I specified the `ValidationData` in the opts.

```
options = trainingOptions("sgdm", ...
    MaxEpochs=8, ...
    ValidationData={XValidation,YValidation}, ...
    ValidationFrequency=30, ...
    Verbose=false, ...
    Plots="training-progress");`
```

Because I want draw a picture including the `YValidation` data (which I specified) and  predicted-`YValidation` data(which derived from the training net).

How can I get the predicted `YValidation` data?